# Display button tooltip on a label for wpf button

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have several WPF buttons on my Page and I want to display tooltips when the mouse is hovered over them.
But I want the tooltip to appear in a label that I have pplaced on my page so I want to show this label and set its text to something.
Whenever the mouse is moved away from the button I want the label to disappear again.

I can change the image of my buton by doin what I learned here: http://www.canofcode.co.uk/software/wpf-rollover-images/
but I cant figure out how to display this tooltip yet....

Comment: <Button x:Name="button1" Content="TestButton" Width="100" Height="50" ToolTip="label1"/>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that using `DataTrigger` on `IsMouseOver` property of button. This is what you are looking for i guess -

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center">
   <Button x:Name="button1" Content="TestButton" Width="100" Height="50"/>
   <Label x:Name="label1" Content="Tooltip Text">
      <Label.Style>
         <Style TargetType="Label">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
               <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=button1, 
                                              Path=IsMouseOver}" 
                            Value="True">
                   <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
               </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
         </Style>
      </Label.Style>
    </Label>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: <Button x:Name="button1" Content="TestButton" Width="100" Height="50" ToolTip="label1"/>